# Import Data-Tier Application vs sqlpackage.exe

Tags: sql-server, import, sqlpackage, bacpac, azure-sql-managed-instance

We are now encountering an error with an automated process when attempting to restore a `.BACPAC` file using the `sqlpackage` utility but are successful when importing the same file using the "Import Data-Tier Application" wizard through SSMS.

The error we are getting is the following:

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>
> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_xx_xx". The conflict occurred in database "TEMP_xxx_5182022", table "dbo.xxx", column 'xxx'.

The automated process exports the `.BACPAC` file from a copy of a database running on an Azure SQL Managed Instance. The `.BACPAC` file then gets imported into SQL Server 2017 using `sqlpackage.exe /a:Import`.

Doing some further research, it sounds like this process will not succeed 100% of the time based on the fact that the exported file does not guarantee transactional consistency. The correct approach would be to generate a COPY ONLY of the DB and export which would require us to make some TDE encryption on that server.

When importing the `.BACPAC` through the Import Data Tier Wizard using SSMS, we are not encountering that error.

Does the wizard use the `sqlpackage.exe` utility or something else?

Are there any missing parameters we could pass to either /Import or /Export that could allow for a successful import?  (i.e. `/p:DisableIndexesForDataPhase`)

Do we have any other options besides using the COPY ONLY method?

Comment: What's the size of database you are exporting as bacpac? When importing via automated process , are you creating destination DB before hand ?

Comment: The size of the DB is around 85GB (mdf).  The exported .bacpac comes out at around 1.5GB.  The DB is not created before hand

Comment: .I think that's the issue. Can you give it a try ? Create a db beforehand and then import bacpac using sqlpackage exe. When the destination db is not created beforehand, SQLPACKAGE.exe creates a db for you in runtime but it can hold max data up to 32 GB.

Comment: Thank you kindly for this suggestion.  I have updated the SQL Server Agent job to include a task to create the db before running the import step.  I will keep my eyes on it and I provide an update in a few weeks.

Comment: @PankajSanwal  Since we added the create DB step, the job has been succeeding every night so I am considering this solved!  Please feel free to add your comment as a reply so I can mark it as the answer and give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the size of the DB being restored.

When SQLPackage.exe is used, you have to 2 options to specify the Target DB

1. Without creating Target DB beforehand. In this scenario, target DB will be created for you at runtime but it has an upper **LIMIT OF 32 GB**. If the Source DB ( Not the BACPAC file size), from which the BACPAC is created is > 32 GB, the restore will fail or exits prematurely.
2. Other and better approach would be to **create an empty DB beforehand and specify it as target DB**. This will bypass the limit issue.